# Jquery mobile with phonegap back to page error?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, sms

I have one sms link in my jquery phonegap application:

`<a class="extLink" id="smsLink" href="sms:5555?body=text"></a>`

After click on link application open messenger and message is inserted.

When i try back to app with back button i received error page: Web page not available-The Web page at sms:5555?body=text might be....

I understand why this occurs, but how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the format for the sms needs to be changed. try one of these,

```
<a href="sms://"></a>

<a href="sms://?body=xxxxxxx">xxxxxx<a>

<a href="sms://+3490322111">Contact us by SMS</a>

<a href="sms://+3490322111?body=xxxxxx">xxxxxx</a>
```

Comment: I thought the case when dynamic open the link with `window.open ($ ("# smsLink"). attr ('href'), '_blank', 'location = yes');`

Comment: Solved:). Using window.location.href = $("#smsLink").attr("href"); instead of window.open ($ ("# smsLink"). attr ('href'), '_blank', 'location = yes');